# Rooms vs Namespaces for a Chat Widget with Admin Dashboard

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm building a chat widget using Facebook Messenger (similar to Intercom live chat or Tawkto or Drift). However, since it's powered by Facebook Messenger user send messages from their Facebook id. The Facebook id of a user will be like pageID_userID (since facebook gives a page scoped user id)

The admin will have a dashboard where he can manage multiple pages and its messages. How can I implement rooms/namespaces in this scenario?

My thoughts: End-user(**pageID_userID**) subscribes to a room named '**pageID_userID**'. When he sends a message, it will be also sent to a room named '**pageID**'. And admin opening the dashboard joins to N rooms. Where N is the number of pages he manages.